# Simplest angular2 setup with webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I'm working through [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-writing-a-simple-angular-2-component) tutorials on Angular2, but they are still using the beta. I'm looking at the docs for [Angular2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) which point to the more up-to-date release candidate, but I can't get the webpack server from the egghead.io lesson to work with the angular2 packages and I'm not really sure where the hangup is.

In `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.9.0",
    "ts-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3",
    "typings": "^0.6.8",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.8",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
```

I haven't changed the [`webpack.config.js`](https://github.com/johnlindquist/intro-to-angular2/blob/master/webpack.config.js) from the one presented in the lesson.

When I do `npm start` (run the webpack server) I keep getting

> `Error during instantiation of NgZone! (ApplicationRef -> ApplicationRef_ -> NgZone).`
>   `Cannot read property 'fork' of undefined`

This would indicate to me that `zone.fork` is not loading. I did update my `vendor.ts` file to:

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

but I still get the same error as above. If I include a simple script tag with `console.log(zone.fork)` it logs a function, so it seems like zone.js is being loaded. I'm not sure why Angular2 won't start or if there is something else I need to include.

Comment: Have you tried wiping your `node_modules` and reinstalling? This smells like a misversioned dep crept in there

Comment: Also, tread lightly with bumping your rxjs version beyond angular's (the peer dependency is on beta-6 in rc0). It'll most likely be fine, but if not you're going to bugs creeping up from deep in the bowels.

Comment: @drewmoore yeah I tried wiping and reinstalling several times. I also tried `beta.6` but I get exactly the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

You are importing

```
"rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.8",
```

but rc.1 is only compatible with beta.6

Comment: Updated to `.6` but this still yields the same issue